# Can I send message header while using kafka-rest proxy api?

Tags: kafka-rest

I want to send message header for kafka message using kafka-rest proxy api. https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html

How can I do this?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka REST API has 2 versions.

Using v2 API its not possible to publish the header information in topic. As it doesn't support that.

Using v3 API there is a possibility to publish the header information in topic. But, you can't consume the messages from the v3 API as consuming the messages are not available.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#records-v3